# Magento 2 - changing core code css/html not reflecting in front end

Tags: html, css, magento2

I installed **Magento 2** - Luma theme using XAMPP.

When I try to change one heading for example, from **Admin Panel** - everything is working.It displays changed heading in the front end correctly.

When I try do the same from **core code** - it's not working.

I save everything in core core when change something. Delete cache.Change browsers - none of these working.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to reflect the changes in css/html on run time, you have to change in pub/static/front end/magento/theme/css contents, then you can check the result on front end, if you are doing the changes in code folder you have to clean/flush the cache, still you are not seeing the result, just run the deployment command. everything will be working fine.

Answer (score 0):

You have to to use [Flush JavaScript/CSS Cache](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K4wrr.png)

and Flush Static Files Cache